# Double integration question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can i solve this double integration? $$I=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{x}^\infty \frac{1}{y} \mathrm e^\frac{-y}{2}dydx$$.No idea.Please help me with a hint.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of integration?

Comment: What will that help?

Comment: what about this: [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB_0%5E%E2%88%9E%E2%88%AB_x%5E%E2%88%9E%28e%5E%7B-y%2F2%7D%2Fy%29+dy+dx ]

Comment: What if OP is asked the same question on an exam and can't use a computer or a calculator?

Answer (score 5):

By [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) the interchanging of $\int$ signs is allowed so

$$I=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{x}^\infty \frac{1}{y}  e^\frac{-y}{2}dydx=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^y\frac1ye^\frac{-y}{2}dxdy=\int_0^\infty e^\frac{-y}{2}dy=-2e^\frac{-y}{2}dx\Big|_0^\infty=2$$

Comment: How did the limit change from x->$\infty$ to 0->y?

Comment: To see this draw the region of the plane $$\{(x,y)\;|\; 0\le x\wedge x\le y\}$$